# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.5. Add google Maven repository and sync project

Tags: maven, android-studio

[image]

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.5.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom
- https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.5/gradle-6.5.pom
  Required by:
  project :
  Add google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File

Comment: Please check if offline gradle toggle is enabled or not. Also, use the latest version: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.2-all.zip` in your `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the google repo in this build.Gradle(project level)

go into your buidl.gradle(:project level) and add this line :

```
repositories {
google() // add this
}
```